# Not able to override file log pattern in spring boor v1.2.6 of spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I did lots of search but didn't find right answer. By default spring boot logs messages with millisecs. I need logging timestamp in secs only or microsecs. (I think, I can 000 at end of millisecs for microsecs).

Hence, I want to override this property

```
<property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wex"/>
```

Spring boot documentation says, if logback.xml is there in classpath, it will override it's properties. (I know, 1.2.x branch doesn't allow overriding in application.properties). Then I added logback.xml file in classpath like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wex"/>
</configuration>
```

But it's not working for me. Any help will be appreciated. I don't want to upgrade my application to 1.3.x yet.

Comment: Check if removing the include tag line helps

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured out. We need to override whole default logback configuration. So we put logback.xml in classpath. 
Here is my file, which is overriding log pattern for console & file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
<!-- Defined variables etc. -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

<!-- overridden two properties -->
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}000){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wex"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}000 %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wex"/>

<!--  copied from base.xml -->      
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there's a "bug" in defaults.xml of the spring-boot.jar related to file-appender. The value cannot be overridden. Please see the following:

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
<property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
```

This configuration doesn't allow you to override the file level pattern (`logging.pattern.file`)

The fix is available in later versions. In Springboot 1.5.3, the config is now fixed:

```
<property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
```